# SOQL query between non relational objects

Tags: soql

I am having a query like this

```
SELECT Staff__c  FROM Application_Contact__c WHERE Application__c IN (SELECT Application__c FROM Address__c where  Provider__c ='0010w00000A6MsTAAV')
```

In the above query Application_Contact__c  is a junction object which is related to Application and contact objects

Address__c is having a look up relation to Application object

The above query runs fine but i want some columns from Address__c and Some colums from application object also

ie,

- Staff_C from Application_Contact__c object
- StreetAddress from Address__c object
- Name from Application__c object

Is it possible to achieve through single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could run a query on `Application__c` and use child selects to get the two objects you want:

```
select Name, (select Staff__c from Application_Contacts__r),
      (select StreetAddress from Addresses__r) from Application__C 
       where Id in (select Application__c from Address__c where Provider__c = '001...')
```

In Apex, this will generate a list of `Application__c` objects which have two related lists, `Application_Contacts__r` and `Addresses__r`, which will be a list of all those objects related to that Application.  If you want, you can do a where filter on the subjoin, so you could do something like `(select StreetAddress from Addresses__r where Provider__c = '001...')` if you only want Addresses that are related to that provider in the child list.  Note that the names of the list relationship are custom so you'll need to check your relation definition to see the right name.

Comment: Thank You.Works like charm.